# how could i change the background color of a select option menu when i hover over it?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Actually the default background color of the select option menu when hovered over it is blue. but i want to change it and modify it according to my choice using bootstrap 5 and css as well as.
some help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried, include the code of your attempt in your question and also outline what research you have done - because the select element and its options are notoriously difficult to style! You may find you have to create your own lookalike (there's lots of examples out there - have a go).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
option:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

simply added option hover css in your file

Answer (score -1):

Find element with (right mouse click - inspect), copy css and change desired color

And create own css

color: #ffffff;
background-color: #f3969a;

Comment: You may not have tried this because the way select and its options are styled are rather built-in to the browser.

Comment: The question asked for the 'selected' option, and using your method - since most people don't set the selected css manually for options menus - won't get them what they need.